# SUMIFS formula doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

This is a simplified example of my problem:

[SUMIFs formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pYMs.png)

I have two columns: category and hours. I want to find the sum of hours for A and C. The answer should be 5.1, but it shows 0. If I use SUMIF formula just for A or C, then it works, but if I use it for both A and C, it shows 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SUMIFS to work all of the criteria should be met, therefore you're saying SUM if Column A is equal to A and C and none of the columns meets it. You can try:

`SUM(SUMIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,{D2,D3}))` or `SUMIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,D2)+SUMIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,D3)`

Comment: And actually if you do so, you no longer need to use SUMIFS you can get the same results with SUMIF